# Does preg_replace use a regular expression to target, or some other format?

Tags: php, regex, function, replace, targeting

I am trying to replace all occurrences of one ot the groups of three letters (in capital) followed by 5 numbers (0-9) and then replace them with a link. Nothing I've done so far seems to work. This is what I have at the moment.

```
return preg_replace("(MTM|SIR|FDF|TAA)[0-9]{5}", "<a href='$&'>$&</a>", $str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a capturing group in your case since you can refer to the whole pattern with $0. And you must add delimiters to your pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?>MTM|SIR|FDF|TAA)\d{5}~', '<a href="$0">$0</a>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a backreference to the characters by wrapping them in a group. Then use `$1` to refer to the contents of the first group.

```
return preg_replace("/((?:MTM|SIR|FDF|TAA)[0-9]{5})/", "<a href='$1'>$1</a>", $str);
```

Also, you'll probably want `(MTM|SIR|FDF|TAA)` instead of `[MTM|SIR|FDF|TAA]{3}`. This means you must have either `MTM`, `SIR`, `FDF` or `TAA`.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I copied and modified the pattern from the OP's solution. I'll edit my answer.